# Cookies being created but unable to echo them

Tags: php

At the end of my registration script I set a cookie of 'loggedin' like so

> setcookie("loggedin", $username,  time()+60*60*24*30 );

And then just redirect back to the home page.

I'm trying to echo out the contents of that cookie. I can see it has been created when I go right click > page info > security > view cookies.

The name of the cookie is there, 'logged in' with contents set to as the username I register as. But when I do something like

> print_r ($_COOKIE);

Nothing shows.

Doing a

> var_dump($_COOKIE);

Gives

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Why might this behavior be occurring if I can see that the cookie is indeed there when I follow the previous steps mentioned?

Comment: Are you trying to echo the cookie on _the same script_ before redirection? `$_COOKIE` won't be populated until the next HTTP request.

Comment: When you view the cookie, what does the path say? What are the paths you're trying to use when you access the cookies on your server?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No I was adding the user to the database, creating the cookie and then redirecting. I was then trying to echo the cookie on the page that the user was redirected to.

Comment: @nickb I had no paths set previously. This has been rectified thanks to the answer below and is now echoing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it can be caused because you don't have the domain/path item set. Try Using:

```
setcookie("loggedin", $username, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', $domain);
```

Comment: Ah yes this works great. But does the '/' mean that the cookie is only viewable on the index page?

Comment: from php.net [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) `The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.`

Comment: I must have missed that. Thanks heaps!

Comment: No problem that's what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

you should store cookies BEFORE any output

because cookies are contained in http header, so if you start output of your html page and store cookies after that - nothing will be stored